# What is the way to describe something that can be wielded with one/two hands?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

For example, are any of these terms correct?

1. two hand sword
2. two hands sword
3. two-hand sword
4. two handed sword
5. two-handed sword

Comment: I would likely take a two-handed sword to have two handles itself, not necessarily used with my hands. I'd use two-hand to indicate use by two hands.

Answer (score 5):

The proper term is "two-handed". The ngram  below  shows that in  comparison "two hand"  is hardly used.

[image]

However, this argument makes abstraction of an important fact pointed out by [user Global Charm](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593806/what-is-the-way-to-describe-something-that-can-be-wielded-with-one-two-hands/593807?noredirect=1#comment1492517_593807) in the comments: "two hand" has a meaning of its own. Anyway, this fact  has  little incidence on  the present answer.

Whereas "two-handed" means (most often) (**A**) "*conceived to be handled using two hands*",  "two-hand" means (often enough) (**B**) "*made or performed using optionally two hands rather than one*". We  have below three typical cases of this use of  "two-hand" (two of  them are of a well kown  sort and  all come from written sources).

- Learning a two—hand backhand will give you a very powerful, versatile shot. (*tennis*)
- Today we are going to learn how to execute a two-hand overhead throw. (*basket-ball*)
- Research has also documented a two-hand advantage in Braille reading and in tactile pattern-recognition tasks  (*Braille reading*)

Nevertheless, this usage is not perfect and this is seen first in the following example where "two-hand" is actually taken as "two-handed"                 (from Google Books).

- A two-hand device requires application of both hands to operate the power press and shall require manual operation of both controls until a point is reached in the cycle where opening is such that the operator cannot remove his hands

It seems possible to deduce now  that   **user Global  Charm**'s objection points to  the  first ngram being apparently worthless since "two hand" in "two hand  sword" should  have two  meanings. However, this is not so; "two hand" has to modify "sword", and as  such can't be explained by  meaning "**B**". This  rather evident contention is confirmed by means of an ngram obtained after the addition of  the indefinite  article: the same curve results  (approximately).

[image]

This confirms  a  real misuse of "two hand"  (according to the ideal of two existing  definitions).

A more general ngram  (below), in which the noun  can be anything, shows that this usage is the correct  one for  all nouns.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The proper term is the one that conveys the author’s intended meaning. *Two-hand* and *two- handed* have different meanings. Frequency of use is not a good indicator here, any more than it would be in finding the “proper” color for a rose.

Comment: @GlobalCharm I  hadn't thought about this second  definition; it is an important fact that  should be mentioned. However, as pertains to  the ngram argument  I believe your remarks have no incidence on my results,  that being so because  of a particularity  of the context. I made an addition to my post so as  to show that (and  add the definition you metion).

Comment: You mention "two **head**" in paragraph 2, after the first ngram.  I definitely agree that "two head" has its own meaning and that it has little/no relevance to your answer (or to the question, for that matter.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @PapaPoule You are not, that is what I meant, and in fact you caught a little imprecision  (little/no relevance); as I thought about this again I saw that I am the one who missed  something; there _is_ a significant incidence: no possible generalization (3rd ngram, ¶ above it). The nature of the noun is determinig; perhaps you noticed. For instance, for "two-hand backhand" the action (backhand) is the same (1/2 hands), but for "two-hand sword" the sword is not the same as for "one-hand sword". I will preserve my answer as it is until you have checked, it and then I'll delete this 3rd ngram.

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what Papa Poule was saying. You said "head", as in the thing on top of the body, where the eyes and mouth and brain are. Are you sure that's the word you wanted to use there?

Comment: @user2357112 Oh! Right! I  overlooked  that detail… It's "hand". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please note: This appears to be about weaponry (you used "wielded" in the question).
Weaponry has its own domain specific jargon and technical terms.

Generally there are 3 basic categories of melee weapons:

1. One-handed weapon: needs 1 hand to wield.
2. Two-handed weapon: needs 2 hands to wield. A very strong person might be able to wield it one-handed, but not for long (because it is heavy) and with less efficiency because the weapon is to cumbersome (size and balance) for purely one-handed operation.
3. Hand-and-a-half of bastard weapon: Can be wielded both ways. (The term "bastard" is, as far as I know, only used with swords.)

Hand and a half weapons typically are the same size/weight to about 1.5x bigger/heavier than one-handed weapons.
They usually have an extra long handle/grip that allows the wielder to place the second hand on the handle too, to put more power into a blow or cut and/or to better guide the weapon if precision is required.

Depending on context you will have to decide what best describes your weapon. This may depend on how and by who the weapon is used.
E.g. For a hobbit a man-sized one-handed sword will probably serve as a bastard sword or even a two-handed sword. (In the "Lord of the Rings" the hobbits use short swords that are actually knives for men or elves.)

Answer (score 1):

If something is ***two-handed*** it may as well mean that two persons are required to use it. ***Two-handed*** is also applied to a person without a dominating hand (i.e. a person is neither left-handed or right-handed).

There is also the term ***ambidextrous*** which is also applied to both persons and objects — while an ***ambidexter*** is always a person, but that latter term is archaic

But there is one more term: ***bimanual***. And this one is applied only to items

(But if anyone is speaking about wielding a sword or a mace, then two-handed is the correct description.)